# these title are based on the major confusion about uses of AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my homepage AJAX is working properly, but after some action when I again return this same page, AJAX not working, until I again run CodeIgniter. I am using CodeIgniter 3.0.2

What should I do?

**Model:**

```
<?php
class tele extends CI_Model
{
    public function industry_fetch()
    {
        $qr=$this->db->query("select * from industry");
        if($qr)
        {
            return $qr->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function subindustry_fetch()
    {
        $qr=$this->db->query("select * from subindustry");
        if($qr)
        {
            return $qr->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function company_fetch()
    {
        $qr=$this->db->query("select * from company");
        if($qr)
        {
            return $qr->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function contact_fetch($v)
    {
        $qr=$this->db->query("select * from company where NAME like '$v%'");
        if($qr)
        {
            return $qr->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function company_registration()
    {
        $cname=mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('n'));
        $cemail=mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('e'));
        $cpassword=mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('p'));
        $cadress=mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('ad'));
        $cphone=mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('cn'));
        $ctime=mysql_real_escape_string($this->input->post('st'));
        $csi=$this->input->post('si');
        $qr=$this->db->query("select * from subindustry where NAME='$csi'");
        $r=$qr->row();
        //print_r($r);
        //exit;
        $csiid=$r->S_ID;
        $qry=$this->db->query("insert into company values('','$cname','$cemail','$cpassword','$cadress','$cphone','$ctime','$csiid',0)");
        if($qry)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function login_fetch()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('e');
        $password=$this->input->post('p');
        $qr=$this->db->query("select * from company where EMAIL='$email' and PASSWORD='$password'");
        $r=$qr->num_rows();
        if($r==1)
        {
            $row=$qr->row();
            $id=$row->C_ID;

            $this->session->set_userdata('id',$id);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function login_success()
    {
        $p=$this->session->userdata('id');
        $qr=$this->db->query("select * from company where C_ID='$p'");
        if($qr)
        {
            $st=$qr->row();//mysql_fetch_row()
            return $st;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by this "_when I again return this same page, AJAX are not working, until I again run CodeIgniter_"?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are running your ajax call onclik function like this

```
$('.yourclass').click(function(){

  $.ajax({
   Your code

   })
})
```

change this to this

```
$(document).on('click','.yourclass',function(){

      $.ajax({
       Your code

       })
    })
```

Or you can run the ajax call on onclick function with java script it will give you any error.
Read this tutorial for how to run ajax on javascript onclick function dynamically without page refresh. 
http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Both of your codes do exactly the same thing. In fact `.click()` is a shorthand form of `.on('click', ...)`.

Comment: I know that both the code are same but when you are using both with Ajax it $(document).on('click', will work better this is personal experience

Comment: Actually, there is no _works better_ factor at all. The real purpose when developers make use of `$(document).on()` is _event delegation_ by means of which elements that don't even exist in the DOM will have there event handlers registered via _bubbling_ of the event they raise.